# why convolution of x and y is different ifft(fft(x)xfft(y))?

Tags: matlab, time, fft, convolution

I know that convolution of x and y in time domain is equal to fft(x) times by fft(y) in frequency domain.
so I tried simple example using matlab as below.

```
xn=[1,2,3,4];
yn=[4,3,2,1];
zn=conv(xn,yn);

znr=ifft(fft(xn).*fft(yn));
```

and I got the result as below.

zn =
4    11    20    30    20    11     4
znr =
24    22    24    30

I wonder why zn is not equal to znr.
Anyone who knows why pls explain.

Comment: The FFT imposes a periodic boundary condition, whereas `conv` assumes zeros outside the input domain. Add four zeros to `xn` and to `yn`, then try again. Also use the `'same'` option in `conv`.

Comment: I tried it as your comment, but the order is still different. xn=[0,0,1,2,3,4,0,0];
yn=[0,0,4,3,2,1,0,0];

zn=conv(xn,yn,'same')
znr=ifft(fft(xn).*fft(yn))

zn =
     4    11    20    30    20    11     4     0
znr =
   20.0000   11.0000    4.0000   -0.0000    4.0000   11.0000   20.0000   30.0000, 

and could you explain me more about the concept of periodic boundary condition of FFT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying the transform length when taking the `fft()` to configure the solution in the way you want may be a solution. Since typically the result of convolution has a length that is equal to the sum of the two signals convolved subtract 1 we can then set the `Transform_Length` to 7 in this case.

```
xn = [1,2,3,4];
yn = [4,3,2,1];
zn = conv(xn,yn);

Transform_Length = length(xn) + length(yn) - 1;
znr = ifft(fft(xn,Transform_Length).*fft(yn,Transform_Length));

zn
znr
```

### Result:

[image: Convolution Result]

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: Thank you so much, its nice to understand.